# Is it a good idea to put all className classes as a prop in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm just wondering is putting your `className` classes inside the prop in React class? Here is my code so far.

```
var app = document.getElementById('app');
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return(
         <div>
            <Header navbar="navbar fixed-top navbar-custom"/>
         </div>
      ); 
   }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
   render() {
      return(
         <header>
            <div class={this.props.navbar}>
               <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Material Site</a>
               <a href="#"><img src="/images/hamburger-icon.png" width="30" height="20"></img></a>
            </div>
         </header>
      );
   }
}

class ChildSidebar extends React.Component {}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);
```

Thanks for the constructive advice.

Comment: `<div class={this.props.navbar}>` should be `<div className={this.props.navbar}>` as `class` is the reserved keyword. Same for  `<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">`. See this https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#how-do-i-add-css-classes-to-components

Comment: Unless the classname changes according to some condition or in different instance of the Header component, its probably better to write them as a static value inside the component, else a prop is okay. Also in JSX use className instead of class

Comment: Ah yes my bad the class works within my live server and doesnt flag as an error, but I will change this thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) is also a helpful tool to dynamically build a class name. You could the e.g. introduce a `fixedToTop` prop and set its corresponding class name if it is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bad idea.

Just prefer use `className` React attribute instead of `class`

```
<header>
    <div className={this.props.navbar}>
                /* Your code */
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say , why don't you instantiate a class object in state? so the properties of the class will be in the props.

Answer (score 1):

Is it good idea? yes. Everytime? No
I would suggest you should only do this where the component is reusable in the global scope of the application. There are some cases when the html structure is usually same but the classes name are different. In these you can make classNames as props (also set default classes as default value).
In the end it is the design choice really of what level of generalization you need to have with your component some times abstracting everything means you need to manage everything which could be frustrating at times.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a good idea or not, in fact, everything relays on your implementation logic.

You'll always find many ways to do the same implementation, the best one I would say, is the one that relays at most on the [SOLID Principles](https://hackernoon.com/solid-principles-made-easy-67b1246bcdf).

Let's see some example of the same implementation you exposed:

1) Exposing only Header `boolean properties` to customise the behaviour:

```
const app = document.getElementById('app');
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return(
         <div>
            <Header isFixed isCustom />
         </div>
      ); 
   }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
   render() {
      const { isFixed, isCustom } = this.props;
      return(
         <header>
            <div className=`navbar ${isFixed ? 'fixed-top' : ''} ${isFixed ? 'navbar-custom' : ''}`>
               <a href="#" className="navbar-brand">Material Site</a>
               <a href="#"><img src="/images/hamburger-icon.png" width="30" height="20"></img></a>
            </div>
         </header>
      );
   }
}

class ChildSidebar extends React.Component {}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);
```

2) Extending the `css class` for unpredictables behaviour:

```
const app = document.getElementById('app');
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return(
         <div>
            <Header classExtended='fixed-top' />
         </div>
      ); 
   }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
   render() {
      const { classExtended } = this.props;
      return(
         <header>
            <div className=`navbar navbar-custom ${classExtended}`>
               <a href="#" className="navbar-brand">Material Site</a>
               <a href="#"><img src="/images/hamburger-icon.png" width="30" height="20"></img></a>
            </div>
         </header>
      );
   }
}

class ChildSidebar extends React.Component {}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);
```

3) You own example.

The best case scenario is analyse with those cases might fit better for your project requirements and life cycle, giving you the ability to refactor your code with easy.

Answer (score 0):

To judge if this is a good idea, it is important to think about where the approach to pass classNames as props is leading when your application growth. In a complex application you would probably end-up managing your data as well as your classNames in a top-level component and pass both down to child components.

However, isn't data what effects your dynamic styles?

So it would be better to manage your dynamic assignment of classes within components and only pass the bits of data to components they need to render.

So long story short: It doesn't scale so don't do it if you want to build a complex app.